# How can I override ExpansionPanelSummary deep elements with styled-components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

Using [the docs/examples](https://material-ui.com/guides/interoperability/#deeper-elements) for overriding Material UI styling with styled-components, I've managed to style the root and "deeper elements" within an `ExpansionPanel` and `ExpansionPanelDetails`.

However, when I use the same technique to return an overridden `ExpansionPanelSummary` from a function passed to `styled()`, the `ExpansionPanelSummary` moves in the DOM and the whole `ExpansionPanel` no longer renders correctly.

The technique in question, as applied to `ExpansionPanel` (this works as expected, on the container `ExpansionPanel`):

```
import MUIExpansionPanel from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanel';

export const ExpansionPanel = styled(props => (
  <MUIExpansionPanel
    classes={{expanded: 'expanded'}}
    {...props}
  />
))`
  && {
    ...root style overrides
  }
  &&.expanded {
    ...expanded style overrides
  }
`;
```

The typical DOM (with class names abbreviated) for `ExpansionPanel` and friends:

```
<div class="MuiExpansionPanel...">
  <div class="MuiExpansionPanelSummary..." />
  <div class="MuiCollapse-container...>
    <div class="MuiCollapse-wrapper...>
      <div class="MuiCollapse-wrapperInner...>
        <div class="MuiExpansionPanelDetails..." />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The DOM when I apply the above technique to `ExpansionPanelSummary`:

```
<div class="MuiExpansionPanel...">
  <div class="MuiCollapse-container...>
    <div class="MuiCollapse-wrapper...>
      <div class="MuiCollapse-wrapperInner...>
        <div class="MuiExpansionPanelSummary..." />
        <div class="MuiExpansionPanelDetails..." />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For completeness, here's a minimal repro of what I'm doing to `ExpansionPanelSummary`, that triggers the DOM switch:

```
export const ExpansionPanelSummary = styled(props => (
  <MUIExpansionPanelSummary
    {...props}
  />
))``;
```

And my JSX is standard `ExpansionPanel` setup:

```
<ExpansionPanel>
  <ExpansionPanelSummary>
    Summary Label
  </ExpansionPanelSummary>
  <ExpansionPanelDetails>
    <div>Some Content</div>
  </ExpansionPanelDetails>
</ExpansionPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This difficulty is independent of using styled-components and just has to do with wrapping `ExpansionPanelSummary` in another component.

You can similarly reproduce this with the following wrapping of `ExpansionPanelSummary`:

```
const MyCustomSummary = props => {
  return (
    <ExpansionPanelSummary {...props} expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
      <Typography>{props.text}</Typography>
    </ExpansionPanelSummary>
  );
};
```

There are several component groups like this where a Material-UI parent component looks for a particular type of child component and treats that child specially. For instance, you can find the following block in [`ExpansionPanel`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/ExpansionPanel/ExpansionPanel.js#L134)

```
      if (isMuiElement(child, ['ExpansionPanelSummary'])) {
        summary = React.cloneElement(child, {
          disabled,
          expanded,
          onChange: this.handleChange,
        });
        return null;
      }
```

Fortunately, Material-UI has a straightforward way to tell it that your custom component should be treated the same as a particular Material-UI component via the `muiName` property:

```
MyCustomSummary.muiName = "ExpansionPanelSummary";
```

or in your case it would look like:

```
export const ExpansionPanelSummary = styled(props => (
  <MUIExpansionPanelSummary
    {...props}
  />
))``;

ExpansionPanelSummary.muiName = "ExpansionPanelSummary";
```

[image: Edit Custom ExpansionPanelSummary]

Comment: Hot damn, it works. My next step was to start poking around in the source...but it was 5pm Friday. Thanks for doing the detective work for me!

Comment: I'm using TypeScript, so I found that I needed to do `(MyCustomSummary as any).muiName = "ExpansionPanelSummary";` because the types that came out of `withSyles(...styles)(ExpansionPanelSummary)` don't seem to include `muiName`, but it works after that!