# customizing the expansionpanel in material ui and overwriting the styles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to customize the expansionpanel in material ui.I see that the data i want to render on expansion panel takes too much space because of the default styling of the expansion panel.

```
   <ExpansionPanel   defaultExpanded={isCurrentInning}>
        <ExpansionPanelSummary  classes={{ expanded:classes.expandedPanel }} expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon className="label"/>}>
          <div className={classes.inningInfoContainer}>
            <div className={classes.teamNameOrderContainer}>
              <span  className="label">
                 <img   src={image} width="25em" />
                 <span > {battingTeamName}</span>
              </span>
            </div>
    // closing tags of ExpansionPanel and ExpansionPanelSummary
```

I see that the expansion panel has this style by default

```
 MuiExpansionPanelSummary-root-209 {
     display: flex;
     padding: 0 24px 0 24px;
     min-height: 48px;
transition: min-height 150ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1)           0ms,background-color 150ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
}
```

I want to overwrite these default styles .
Here is the simple code on codesandboxlink 
https://codesandbox.io/s/yp9lmvwo1x

Comment: Did you check out https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/?

Comment: Can you explain as how to over ride in this case ?.MuiExpansionPanelSummary-root-210

Answer (score 3):

You can find examples of overriding ExpansionPanelSummary styles in the documentation here: https://material-ui.com/demos/expansion-panels/#customized-expansion-panel

In order to understand in more detail how to override these styles appropriately, it is helpful to look at the [source code for ExpansionPanelSummary](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/ExpansionPanelSummary/ExpansionPanelSummary.js) in order to see how the default styles are defined.

Here is an abbreviated version of the default styles that only includes the parts impacting the height:

```
export const styles = theme => {
  return {
    /* Styles applied to the root element. */
    root: {
      minHeight: 8 * 6,
      '&$expanded': {
        minHeight: 64,
      },
    },
    /* Styles applied to the root element if `expanded={true}`. */
    expanded: {},
    /* Styles applied to the children wrapper element. */
    content: {
      margin: '12px 0',
      '&$expanded': {
        margin: '20px 0',
      },
    },
  };
};
```

You can then create your own custom summary component that overrides these styles with something like the following:

```
const summaryStyles = {
  root: {
    minHeight: 7 * 4,
    "&$expanded": {
      minHeight: 7 * 4
    }
  },
  content: {
    margin: "4px 0",
    "&$expanded": {
      margin: "4px 0"
    }
  },
  expandIcon: {
    padding: 3
  },
  expanded: {}
};
const CompactExpansionPanelSummary = withStyles(summaryStyles)(
  ExpansionPanelSummary
);
CompactExpansionPanelSummary.muiName = "ExpansionPanelSummary";
```

You can find details about why the `muiName` property is necessary here: [How can I override ExpansionPanelSummary deep elements with styled-components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55426843/how-can-i-override-expansionpanelsummary-deep-elements-with-styled-components/55427389#55427389)

Here is a working example based on the sandbox you included in your question:

[image: Edit Compact ExpansionPanelSummary]

Answer (score 0):

I raised the same question here:

[MUI Expansion Panel Summary expanded override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61458978/mui-expansion-panel-summary-expanded-override)

In https://codesandbox.io/s/zl4141wm44 if you add minHeight:0 to line 18 of demo.js, why does the minHeight gets ignored.

expanded: { width: "85%", minHeight: 0, backgroundColor: "red" }

I can see that this answer is somehow to suppress .MuiExpansionPanelSummary-root.Mui-expanded.

The solution above creates a custom component and the same issue raised in the github repo (https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13576)  overrides the expansion behaviour in a theme.

Basically I am asking whether you can override this CSS class in styles without creating a custom component or creating a new theme.

Could someone fork https://codesandbox.io/s/zl4141wm44 to show it can be done just with styles?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue as you.
There is a way to override the defaults in your own style classes:

```
root: {             
'& .Mui-expanded': {
minHeight: 0,
},
width: '100%',
},
```

Where 'root' is the className given to the Accordion component. This then ovverides whatever you need to. For me, I only changed it so that the size does not increase when expanding.