# How to style Material UI expansion panel Text

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, frontend, material-ui, expansion

I am trying to decrease the space on the Expansion Panel on the top and bottom. I tried to set padding as 0 but it did not work.

```
panel: {
  backgroundColor: background.paper,
  position: "absolute",
  padding: spacing(0),
},
text: {
  color: text.secondary,
  padding: spacing(0),
},
summary: {
  minHeight: spacing(0),
},
details: {
  padding: spacing(0, 1, 2, 1),
},
icon: {padding: spacing(0),},

        <ExpansionPanel
        expanded={expanded}
        onChange={onClick}
        className={classes.panel}
      >
        <ExpansionPanelSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon className={classes.icon} />}
          className={classes.summary}
        >
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.text}>
            StackOverFlow
          </Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelSummary>
        <ExpansionPanelDetails className={classes.details}>
          <Keys />
        </ExpansionPanelDetails>
      </ExpansionPanel>
```

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [customizing the expansionpanel in material ui and overwriting the styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55516006/customizing-the-expansionpanel-in-material-ui-and-overwriting-the-styles)

Comment: @RyanCogswell : Not sure. I am overwriting the styling and they are happening correctly. My problem is more on which styling to overwrite etc. I want to reduce the top and bottom spacing on the StackOverFlowt ext. Thank you.

Comment: If you are trying to reduce the ExpansionPanelSummary height, the example in the other answer does this (I just now fixed it to work with the latest version of Material-UI -- when I first wrote the answer, I think the IconButton padding did not impact the height in the same manner).

Comment: @RyanCogswell Thank you so much. I added minHeight : spacing (0) in classes.panel. It did not work for me :(

Comment: My example does not use `classes.panel`, so I wouldn't expect that to work.

Comment: It is the classes that ExpansionPanel is using. You are setting the same style in "root" element in your code for the div. I do not feel that name we use matter much in adding custom styling.

Comment: That `root` class in my example is going on `ExpansionPanelSummary`, **not** `ExpansionPanel`.

Comment: @RyanCogswell added minHeight to Summary as well. Did not change anything for me 
:(

Comment: And you need all four classes from my example on the `ExpansionPanelSummary` (`root`, `content`, `expandIcon`, and `expanded`) passed via the `classes` prop (or use `withStyles` as in my example) **not** via the `className` prop.