# ExpansionPanelSummary not working when wrapped

Tags: material-ui, accordion

I'm trying to wrap **ExpansionPanelSummary** with a component like below.

```
const CollapsibleSummary = ({ children, ...props }) =>
  <ExpansionPanelSummary {...props} >
    {children}
  </ExpansionPanelSummary>;
```

Is there something wrong I'm doing?

But when I do

```
const CollapsibleSummary = ExpansionPanelSummary
```

It's working very well.

Thnx in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I override ExpansionPanelSummary deep elements with styled-components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55426843/how-can-i-override-expansionpanelsummary-deep-elements-with-styled-components)

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet solved my issue.

```
CollapsibleSummary.muiName = "ExpansionPanelSummary";
```