# Custom component within ExpansionPanel fails to render

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Why doesn't the following code render the clusters?

If I directly use ExpansionPanelSummary (as shown in the code comments) then the clusters render properly.

```
function ClusterSummary(props) {
  return (
    <ExpansionPanelSummary>
      <Typography>{props.cluster.title}</Typography>
    </ExpansionPanelSummary>
  );
}

function Clusters(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.clusters.map((cluster) => 
        <ExpansionPanel key={cluster.id} cluster={cluster}>
          {/* <ExpansionPanelSummary>
            <Typography>{cluster.title}</Typography>
          </ExpansionPanelSummary> */}
          <ClusterSummary key={cluster.id} cluster={cluster} />
        </ExpansionPanel>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Interactive link on codestandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-sammet-596ee

I am using material-ui/core 3.9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has the same cause and solution as the question I answered here:

[How can I override ExpansionPanelSummary deep elements with styled-components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55426843/how-can-i-override-expansionpanelsummary-deep-elements-with-styled-components/55427389#55427389)

You need the following to fix it:

```
function ClusterSummary(props) {
  return (
    <ExpansionPanelSummary>
      <Typography>{props.cluster.title}</Typography>
    </ExpansionPanelSummary>
  );
}
// This is what needs to be added
ClusterSummary.muiName = "ExpansionPanelSummary";
```

See my previous answer for details about why this is needed.